# Optimization in Matlab codes

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I want to optimize my program in `Matlab2017`.
I want to repeat some functions `n-times` without using `for-loop`.
For example, in the following code i need removeing for.

```
for i=1:5
    N(i)=diff(f(x),x,i);
end
```

Please help me to optimize this code?
 because i need such codes a lot in my program.

Comment: Give us more information!

Comment: @P.Bn In the above code, i want to calculate derivatives of sin(x) until 5 without using `for-loop`.

Comment: @P.Bn what other information you need?!

Comment: is the derivative symbolic or numeric (or what is f(x)). the way you use `diff` is confusing

Comment: @bla yes, My derivative is symbolic